# Передать изображение post запросом на сервер

Tags: php, java, android, fileupload

Как передать изображение загруженное в ImageView с устройства post запросом на сервер.
Есть поток который передаёт текст на сервер:

```
public class PostThreadUrl extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... jsonObjects) {
        String urlString = "http://newsyou.000webhostapp.com/AddNews.php"; // URL to call
        String urlParameters  = null;
        try {
                urlParameters = "title=" + jsonObjects[0].getString("title") + "&text=" + jsonObjects[0].getString("text") + "&id=" + jsonObjects[0].getString("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;
        String request        = urlString;
        URL    url            = null;
        try {
            url = new URL( request );
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection conn= null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        DataOutputStream wr = null;
        try {
            wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wr.write( postData );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream inputStream= null;
        try {
            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStreamReader isr =new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bRead=new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = bRead.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

       return null;
    }
}
```

Загружается картинка в ImageView:

```
public class NewsReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int Pick_image = 1;
    private ImageView imgAdd;
    private String ImagePath="";
    private File finalFile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_reader);
        imgAdd = findViewById(R.id.imageAdd);
        Button btnLoadImg =findViewById(R.id.LoadImgBtn);
        final Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        btnLoadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {//событие при котором выполняется поиск картинки
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Pick_image);
            }
        });
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.AddNewsBtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//cобытие при котором происходит загрузка на сервер
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView Title=findViewById(R.id.titleAdd);
                TextView Text=findViewById(R.id.textAdd);
                if((!Title.getText().toString().equals(""))&&(!Text.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                    try {
                        Integer id=intent.getIntExtra("id",0);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        jsonObject.put("title", Title.getText().toString());
                        jsonObject.put("text", Title.getText().toString());
                        jsonObject.put("id", id.toString());
                        new PostThreadUrl().execute(jsonObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(NewsReaderActivity.this,"Заполнитте все текстовые поля",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case Pick_image: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
                        ImagePath=finalFile.toString();//Путь к картинке
                        imgAdd.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

php файл который принимает post запрос:

```
<?php
    function getRandomFileName($path, $extension=''){
        $extension = $extension ? '.' . $extension : '';
        $path = $path ? $path . '/' : '';
        do {
            $name = md5(microtime() . rand(0, 9999));
            $file = $path . $name . $extension;
        } while (file_exists($file));
        return $name;
    }
    $path = 'img';
    $target='';
    if($_POST['src']!=""){
        $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['img']['name'], '.'), 1));
        $filename = getRandomFileName($path, $extension);
        $target = $path . '/' . $filename . '.' . $extension;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target);

    }
    $host = 'localhost'; 
    $database = 'NewsBase'; 
    $user = 'mysql'; 
    $password = 'mysql';
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
    $query ="INSERT INTO `News`(`id`, `src`, `title`, `Text`, `a_id`) VALUES (null,'".$target."','".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['text']."',".$_POST['id'].")";
    echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PostThreadUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String urlString = "http://newsyou.000webhostapp.com/AddNews.php"; // URL to call
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        ContentType TextContentType = ContentType.create("text/html",Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        builder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        builder.addTextBody("text", strings[0],TextContentType);
        builder.addTextBody("title", strings[1],TextContentType);
        builder.addTextBody("id", strings[2],TextContentType);
        if(!strings[3].equals("")) {
            File file = new File(strings[3]);
            ContentType fileContentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
            String fileName = file.getName();
            builder.addBinaryBody("img", file, fileContentType, fileName);
            builder.addTextBody("src", strings[3],TextContentType);
        }
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            client.execute(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```